# PayPal forces login and doesn't allow guest checkout when paying an Eventbrite ticket

Tags: paypal

I have an Eventbrite event and PayPal payment method. Some clients (and myself on one of my computers) have trouble: when they want to pay by card on Eventbrite and they click the Mastercard or VISA icon, they are redirected to PayPal page which requires login, instead of to PayPal guest checkout which allows direct card payment. Normally the guest checkout works, but sometimes (possibly for users that have been logged to PayPal previously) this problem occurs.

Notes:

1. I found a workaround, that if I open the Eventbrite page in browser Private window, which removes any cookie and history context, it works and suddenly PayPal guest checkout works. But this is not the solution for the clients.
2. I followed [these instructions to allow PayPal guest checkout](https://support.wix.com/en/article/enabling-guest-checkout-for-paypal-in-your-store) to set in my PayPal business account (the one linked to the Eventbrite page, i.e., the one which collects money from the tickets) the option "PayPal account optional" to "On", but it was already enabled and still this problem occurred.

Comment: Have you contacted PayPal support? I can't imagine that this is expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The situation you've described suggests that the end-users have signed into Paypal (at least once) on the device/computer and elected to be "remembered" on the device, resulting in the cookies being set and subsequent visits to go straight to the account login page.

One recommended solution is to add content/helper text in your Eventbrite event listing, especially if you are providing a direct to a checkout/pay now feature on another website as well. (This is particularly recommended, since it's difficult/bad practice to force a link to open in an incognito/private tab or window.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

Comment: so all your answer suggests is to tell users to open the link in the private window? (I.e. the workaround I found)? Right?